# $.get - Origin not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, macos, google-chrome

Today I've encountered a very strange error while trying to get the contents of a PHP file on my server with `$.get`.

It happens only in Safari and Chrome on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard), on Windows it does work in all browsers properly.

The function is like:

```
function _fc() {
   $.get("_x_fc.php", { xaction: 'login', xv1: $('#login').attr("value"), xv2: $('#pass').attr("value") }, function (data) {

      if (data=='0') { letItGo=true; $('#loginform').submit(); }
      else ...//Do some other checks
   });
}
```

- It's NOT a local server, it's a web server with an existing domain
- I'm NOT trying to perform any cross-domain ajax. Both files are in the same directory.

I can't find any solution for that.

Exact error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://www.asking1.com/_x_fc.php?xaction=login&xv1=something&xv2=something.
Origin http://asking1.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: When you say it only happens on Mac OS X, you're referring to the client OS, right? It's the same server in your Mac OS X tests and your Windows tests?

Comment: I know these are different browsers, but in both of them my code doesn't work. My server is Unix-based, I just test on Windows and Mac Os X. Full error - see editted question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this this way:

```
$.get("http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/_x_fc.php", { xaction: 'login', xv1: $('#login').attr("value"), xv2: $('#pass').attr("value") }, function (data) { (...)
```

You guys are the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in the error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://www.asking1.com/_x_fc.php?xaction=login&xv1=something&xv2=something.
Origin http://asking1.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

`http://www.asking1.com` and `http://asking1.com` are *different* origins, and so this falls afoul of the Same Origin Policy. See the sixth example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

If your code really is as quoted, with the relative URL, that shouldn't be happening, because from the error message the document is on `http://asking1.com`, so the relative path would resolve to `http://askign1.com/_x_fc.php`, which would be fine.

If your code has an absolute path in it, that's your problem. Just remove it to look like your quoted code.

If your code really has the relative path, then you'll need to dig into things a bit. Something, somewhere, is making the browser think the request for `www.asking1.com` content is coming from `asking1.com`.

Comment: But that would only be an issue, if the OP was setting an absolute path for the `$.get` call, where as, they are setting a relative path, in which case, the actual domain would never be different unless there was an .htaccess file redirecting the request.

Comment: @Gavin: True -- assuming that the quoted code is accurate (sadly, I've frequently see code edited to make it shorter that edits out the error). Regardless, the error message is clear that it's an SOP thing.

Answer (score 2):

`www` is technically a sub-domain.  So you are in violation of the `same-origin policy`.  You could resolve this by setting

```
function _fc() {
   document.domain = "www.asking1.com";
   $.get("_x_fc.php", { xaction: 'login', xv1: $('#login').attr("value"), xv2: $('#pass').attr("value") }, function (data) {

      if (data=='0') { letItGo=true; $('#loginform').submit(); }
      else ...//Do some other checks
   });
}
```

or you could fully qualify your URL that you are passing as a part of your AJAX request to ensure that it is the same.